# Netbeans project builds successfully but does not run

Tags: java, netbeans

It displays like To run this application from the command line without Ant.
How can i solve this problem?

Comment: some more details would be appreciated; mind reading isn't the most common virtue among programmers.

Comment: Instead of clicking build, you should click run or debug. Maybe you will need to set up a run configuration.

Comment: Did yo get any error messages?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try to use "Clean & Build" and then "run" - Sometimes NetBeans gets into trouble, when the files are modified outside of Netbeans, or when they're moved. (Or at least NetBeans thinks this has happened)